# How to hold Azure Serive Bus message queue processing on failliure?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm adding service bus message queues to an integration platform when sending data to the third party applications.

Requirement:

- If the third party application is down/network issue/data issue, the process should stop processing the queue. It should hold the entire queue until the 3rd party system is up or data issue fixed.
- If the processing get failed, need to send an email but the message should not moved to the dead letter queue.
- The message should retain at the same point until it can proceed. So that entire queue is on hold state.

Is there any way of handing this flow using Azure service bus Message Queues? or any alternative ways of achieving this?

Regards,

Comment: Is your app processing the messages, or is the integration platform doing the processing? And your third bullet point makes it sound like there are multiple steps to processing each message. Is that correct?

Comment: Integration platform doing the processing. steps means, when a message receives, if i cant deliver that message to the 3rd party app/api, then I send an email notification. And I want to hold the queue to not to process any message after an error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I believe it would be best if the integration platform could be "paused" during the failure and re-activated once the downstream issues are fixed. This could either be a manual process or an automated one if possible.

That being said, Service Bus does provide the ability to [suspend entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/entity-suspend) (queues, topics, subscriptions). Once aware of a problem, you could disable receiving on the entity the integration platform is listening on. This could be automated as well.